# OpenMrs sync module didn't start

Tags: openmrs

I am a beginner in openmrs developping. I work in a project in with we have download the openmrs core master in github and deploy it in a server an in a pc. We want the server and the pc to synchronize their data; the server will be the father and the pc the child.

The problem is when I install the sync module, I have the following error:
Error while trying to start module
Error while running sql: INSERT INTO scheduler_task_config (name, description, schedulable_class, start_time, start_time_pattern, repeat_interval, start_on_startup, started, created_by, date_created, changed_by, date_changed, uuid) VALUES ('Cleanup Old Sync Records', 'This task deletes old rows in the sync_record and sync_server_record tables.  The default settings work on all servers, but for advanced users, you can change the properties to suit your needs.', 'org.openmrs.module.sync.scheduler.CleanupSyncTablesTask', '2009-12-18 17:26:31', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss', '604800', '1', '0', '1', '2009-12-18 17:28:39', null, null, 'd3122955-00d7-454c-b17f-e3f87206c74b') . Message: Duplicate entry 'd3122955-00d7-454c-b17f-e3f87206c74b' for key 'scheduler_task_config_uuid_index'

So I have look for a solution and one of them said that it is a problem of version. The version of my openmrs is 1.12.0 and in the downloading sync module page, it is specify that the version required is 1.9.0. I have supposed that it is the smallest version, otherwise openmrs 1.12 could not be synchronised. One other solution told me to check the version in global_property table and I do it and the problem stay.

Please, anyone of you, can he know how could I start sync module in openmrs 1.12.0? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An openmrs developper said to me that to his knowledge, he did not yet see an openmrs project with use sync module that has a version greater than 1.9. Base on that, and on the fact that in the mostly modules we talk of versions 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, I decided to come back to an openmrs core version 1.9.x and at the first try it works. The sync module started perfectly.